# What is the best way to do a list[0] with a default value in python?

Tags: python

I am looking for a list functionnality in Python.

I am doing this :

```
abcd = [1, 2, 3, 4]
try:
    item = list[5]
except:
    item = 0
```

How can I make it looks like :

```
item = abcd.get(5, 0)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: the try/except method you already have is the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add a `get` method to the `list` class, but you can use either a function:

```
def get(alist, index, default):
  try: return alist[index]
  except IndexError: return default
```

which gives you the usage example:

```
abcd = [1, 2, 3, 4]
item = get(abcd, 5, 0)
```

or a subclass of `list`:

```
class mylist(list):
  def get(self, index, default):
    try: return self[index]
    except IndexError: return default
```

which gives you the usage example:

```
abcd = mylist([1, 2, 3, 4])
item = abcd.get(5, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would not want to dedicate more than one line to this operation. As such I would go for something like `item = len(abcd) > 5 and abcd[5] or 0`.

A **very important** note on this technique, though, is that the element you want (`abcd[5]` in this case) must not evaluate to a boolean `False` value. If it does, the above statement will be evaluated to `0` in stead of the actual (False) value in the list (`None`, `()`, `{}`, etc).